# How to add image taken, from camera intent to the gallery?

Tags: android, camera, gallery

Here's the thing.
I'm building an app that everytime user checks a checkbox it opens camera app in order to take a picture, related to that specific checkbox content. The process of taking the picture and saving it within the app folder is already working. Now I only need to know how to add these taken pictures to the gallery. Below is my photo camera class.

```
public class anexarFotos extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences dadospasta;
String projectName;
File directory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dadospasta = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    projectName = dadospasta.getString("folderDir",null);
    directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + projectName);

    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    finish();

}

String mCurrentPhotoPath;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
ImageView mImageView;

public void obraFolder(){   //Criar a pasta do projeto e o diretório em que os projetos estarão conditos, caso não tenha sido criado.
    if (!directory.exists()){
        directory.mkdirs();
    }

}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {photoFile = createImageFile();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Foto não pode ser armazenada.";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.relatoriodeobras.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }else{
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Atenção! Obrigatório tirar foto!!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
        finish();
        }
    }

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    obraFolder();
    // Create an image file name
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = projectName + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    addImageToGallery(imageFileName, context);

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

public static void addImageToGallery(final String projectName, final Context context) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, projectName);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

}
}
```

The first part displayTakePictureIntent(); is from the original android developer's page. the addImageToGallery method I found out around here. Can you guys please help me? While I was looking for an answer, I saw people using the ContentValues in order to add it to the gallery. Below is what i found.

```
public Uri addImageToGallery(ContentResolver cr, String imgType, File filepath) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "player");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "player");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/" + imgType);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filepath.toString());

    return cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Do I need a ContentValues in order to do that, or my addImageToGallery alone should do the trick?

Many Thanks in advance!